# Time delayed optionally postponable from a second input

Tags: relay, timer

I need functionality similar to that provided by true-off-delay relays, just a little different. I can't come up with a circuit.

I have two inputs (A and B) that I want to control one output (C).

Both inputs can act as resets for the timeout, but only one input (A) can activate the output (C) initially.

I've made an illustration:

[image: Inputs driving outputs over time]

"t" represents a 5 minute timeout, if it is reached then the output needs to switch low

I hope this makes sense!

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please explain what is meant by "t" in the output signal above.  And what distinguished the non-t to the t intervals.  The t seems to be of fixed length.

Comment: Hi rawbrawb, "t" represents a 5 minute timeout.

Comment: Would you be looking for a discrete analog circuit, discrete logic (plus perhaps a 555 timer), or microcontroller based? Could you point us to a starting point from your initial research, please?

Comment: @Anindo, I don't know.  simplest/quickest/cheapest. Ultimately, I'm switching a 12V load that draws 1A continuous, having 2A peaks.  From Olin's answer, it sounds like a job for an MCU :)

Comment: @Jon, exactly as Olin said, I would only add, look for the cheapest, smallest, low pin count mcu that runs without an external crystal, if timing precision is not critical, and dead bug it! I would pick one of the AtTiny 8 pin parts, since I have a few handy.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, purely for completeness: you would still need to add a relay or suitable fet switch, and a means of triggering it from the mcu pins, as no MCU I know of can directly switch the amperage in your requirement... But that is obviously a separate question which has been asked before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a perfect problem for a tiny microcontroller.  Even the tiniest and smallest, the PIC 10F200, can do this job easily.  The logic itself is trivial.  The PIC has a built in oscillator so can perform the 5 minute timeout also.  This is really about as simple as it gets.  You don't want to do 5 minute timing in analog electronics, and then you'd still have to implement the logic function separately.